# Windows Forms C# (DragDrop for 100 objects)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have currently a question for my school-project (we want to develop a Block Puzzle like game).
We build a field (10x10)

I already got to manage the DragDrop for "my field1x1".

```
private void field1x1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            fieldBoxes[0,0].Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        }

foreach (PictureBox checks in fieldBoxes)
            {
                checks.AllowDrop = true;
                checks.DragEnter += field1x1_DragEnter;
                checks.DragDrop += field1x1_DragDrop;
            }
```

and my question is : how can i simplify the code that i don't have to create 100 DragDrops manually?
because

Comment: You should look into the `sender` parameter. It will be the dragged control and after casting it to pbox you can access all its properties. I hope you have either a helpful Name or data in the Tag to work with.. You can map all events to the same code or you could create a pbox subclass. To hook up the events you can use a loop or two.

Comment: thank you! 
worked with these 
private void field1x1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is PictureBox)
            {
                ((PictureBox)sender).Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
private void field1x1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is PictureBox)
            {
                ((PictureBox)sender).Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
            }
            
        }
```

This was the solution